# Making DB connections from within Lambda that is being API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

From what I understand, If I were to stick a lambda function behind API gateway, I would be required to make a RDS connection on every lambda function call. That would slow things down because I wouldn't be able to pool connections. If this is the case, would a migration of some REST services to api gateway + lambda be worth it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AWS Lambda, the code called outside of handler is cached among requests. I do not know which language are you using for your functions but you can check this article to see: http://blog.matthewdfuller.com/2015/12/aws-lambda-occasionally-reliable-caching.html

So if your database connection is done outside of the handler, you keep it between different requests and do not connect to your database for every request.

Comment: A more accurate statement would be: "the code called outside of the handler is ***occasionally*** cached among requests".

Comment: That's true. I would say *generally* because according to our tests you have to have pretty large traffic until a new instance is spawn.

Answer (score 1):

You should see some connection reuse, especially at sustained load. Some requests would get a warm container that had recently processed the same function so as Cagatay mentioned, any code outside the handler could potentially be initialized.

The handler code should be able to set up to use an open connection, or establish a new one if necessary.